# Erro em cadastro "Não reconhece a propriedade"

Tags: java, java-ee

Estou estudando java EE e me deparei com um erro, se alguém souber a resposta eu agradeço.
Tenho o meu form:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">



    <h:form>
       <div>
           <h:outputLabel value="Título"/>
           <h:inputText value="#{adminLivrosBean.Livro.titulo}"/>
       </div>  
       <div>
           <h:outputLabel value="Descrição"/>
           <h:inputTextarea rows="4" cols="20" value="#{adminLivrosBean.livro.descricao}"/>
       </div>    
        <div>
           <h:outputLabel value="Número Páginas"/>
           <h:inputText value="#{adminLivrosBean.Livro.numeroPaginas}"/>
       </div>    
        <div>
           <h:outputLabel value="Preço"/>
           <h:inputText value="#{adminLivrosBean.Livro.preco}"/>
       </div>  

       <h:commandButton value="Cadastrar" action="#{adminLivrosBean.salvar}"/>

    </h:form>



</html>
```

Tenho Bean:

```
package br.com.casadocodigo.loja.beans;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.inject.Named;
import br.com.casadocodigo.loja.models.Livro;

//CDI
@Named
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name="adminLivrosBean")
public class AdminLivrosBean {

    private Livro livro = new Livro();


    public void salvar(){

        System.out.println("Livro Cadastrado:" + livro);

    }


    public Livro getLivro() {
        return livro;
    }


    public void setLivro(Livro livro) {
        this.livro = livro;
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Java é *case sensitive*, ou seja, ele difere entre maiúsculo e minúsculo.

Troque todas as referências do XHTML de `Livro` para `livro` e irá funcionar:

De:

```
<h:form>
   <div>
       <h:outputLabel value="Título"/>
       <h:inputText value="#{adminLivrosBean.Livro.titulo}"/>
   </div>  
   <div>
       <h:outputLabel value="Descrição"/>
       <h:inputTextarea rows="4" cols="20" value="#{adminLivrosBean.livro.descricao}"/>
   </div>    
    <div>
       <h:outputLabel value="Número Páginas"/>
       <h:inputText value="#{adminLivrosBean.Livro.numeroPaginas}"/>
   </div>    
    <div>
       <h:outputLabel value="Preço"/>
       <h:inputText value="#{adminLivrosBean.Livro.preco}"/>
   </div>  

   <h:commandButton value="Cadastrar" action="#{adminLivrosBean.salvar}"/>

</h:form>
```

Para:

```
<h:form>
   <div>
       <h:outputLabel value="Título"/>
       <h:inputText value="#{adminLivrosBean.livro.titulo}"/>
   </div>  
   <div>
       <h:outputLabel value="Descrição"/>
       <h:inputTextarea rows="4" cols="20" value="#{adminLivrosBean.livro.descricao}"/>
   </div>    
    <div>
       <h:outputLabel value="Número Páginas"/>
       <h:inputText value="#{adminLivrosBean.livro.numeroPaginas}"/>
   </div>    
    <div>
       <h:outputLabel value="Preço"/>
       <h:inputText value="#{adminLivrosBean.livro.preco}"/>
   </div>  

   <h:commandButton value="Cadastrar" action="#{adminLivrosBean.salvar}"/>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Igor, agradeço a ajuda, eu fiz exatamente o que você mostra, mais agora eu tenho um outro erro: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: /livros/form.xhtml @13,62 value="#{adminLivrosBean.livro.titulo}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'adminLivrosBean' resolved to null
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)

Comment: @itasouza seu ManagedBean está com escopo de Request. Mude para escopo de View

Comment: Não usa diretamente o atributo 'livro' e sim o getter 'getLivro()'. Por exemplo, mesmo que você tenha o atributo livro, mas não tenha um getLivro() você receberá o erro 'does not have the property 'livro''.

Comment: @mari boa! Estou no celular. Quando estiver no pc atualizo a resposta

Comment: @mari atualizado

Comment: Eu descobri o problema, ´fiz a criação de uma pasta dentro de resources, META-INF, isso resolveu o problema

Answer (score 1):

Onde tiver adminLivrosBean.Livro, troque para adminLivrosBean.livro com 'l' mínusculo.

O servlet ao ver adminLivrosBean.livro irá procurar na classe AdminLivrosBean (classe com anotação @ManagedBean(name="adminLivrosBean")) por um getter getLivro().

Answer (score 0):

Lembre-se de seguir a convenção do JavaBeans.
Se seu bean tem uma propriedade livro, a maioria dos frameworks irá procurar um método getLivro e setLivro para recuperar e gravar dados nesta propriedade.
Troque Livro no template por livro.

Poderá saber mais sobre os padrões javabeans [neste link que leva a um documento da oracle](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf?AuthParam=1505413785_58389a7657c358d4e469401541403058)